# Customizing Active Admin Comments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

Active Admin has those handle comments that go automatically into your admin screens by typing "active_admin_comments"

What I want to do is to add some fields to their comments like a 'status' field. What's the best approach for doing this?

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change defaults, probably the only way is to monkeypatch `build_comment_form`  method of `Comments` class from `active_admin_comments.rb`

You can also make your own comments component by subclassing `ActiveAdmin::Comments:: Views::Comments`, overwriting `build_comment_form` method and using

```
builder_method :my_active_admin_comments_for
```

Just see mentioned `active_admin_comments.rb` for reference.

Comment: Do i just create another file somewhere in my project to create the subclass and the overwritten build_comment_form method?

Comment: Would i need to subclass ActiveAdmin::Comments as well in order to add a field or 2 to the Comment model?

Comment: You can do it in initializer. By subclassing `Views:Comments`, you're modifying only the view. If you want to add new field to active admin comments, just create appropriate migration.